# Url includes subdirectory when using a rewriterule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have just moved a website from one hosting company to another.

On the original host I could have a url like site.com/staff and this would actually call index.php?page=staff using a RewriteRule.  This would work even if that host had a subdirectory with a name of staff.  This applies to more than just the staff page but others also.

On the new host if I call site.com/staff and there is a staff subdirectory I get a URL like:
site.com/staff?page=staff in the address bar.

I am using the same .htaccess on both hosts.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^print/([^/\.]+)/?$ /print.php?page=$1 [R,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)[/]$ /$1 [NC,R]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.?]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

I think it might be a setting in the vhost.conf, httpd.conf or something like this.  I however do not have access to these on the original host.

I can figure out workarounds, but I want to try and get the new server to act like the original.

Comment: You might get more help by asking this on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is being caused by mod_dir and `DirectorySlash`. By default, apache will redirect any request for a directory (regardless of rewrite rules) that's missing the trailing slash to the same request with the trailing slash. This is so that people can't peek into the contents of your directories. If you are missing the trailing slash, directory contents get exposed no matter if you have an index file or not. This redirect ignores any possible rewrite rules that may get applied.

What you;ll need to do is handle the trailing slash in mod_rewrite and turn off mod_dir:

```
DirectorySlash Off

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^print/([^/\.]+)/?$ /print.php?page=$1 [R,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)[/]$ /$1 [NC,R]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.?]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]

# in case there's a request for a directory that hasn't been handled
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L]
```

Comment: Adding the DirectorySlash Off fixed my problem.  How can I set this for all the sites on this server?

Comment: @JohnMason you'd need to do it through the server config, just be aware that directory contents will be exposed if you don't ensure that they can't be accessed.